# TileCache SVN trunk on IIS 7 - An error occurred: No section: 'cache'

Tags: tilecache

I was having tile generation problems with TileCache 2.11 and decided to update to the [trunk](http://svn.osgeo.org/tilecache/trunk/).  I repeated the instructions necessary to get TileCache working in IIS but now I'm seeing this error:

```
An error occurred: No section: 'cache'
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tilecache\TileCache\Configs\File.py", line 147, in read
    self.cache = self._loadFromSection(config, "cache", TileCache.Cache)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tilecache\TileCache\Config.py", line 74, in _loadFromSection
    type  = config.get(section, "type")
  File "C:\Python25\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 511, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
```

I've made the necessary change to tilecache.py:

```
from TileCache import Service, cgiHandler, cfgfiles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    svc = Service.load("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\tilecache\\tilecache.cfg")
    cgiHandler(svc)
```

And I've confirmed my configuration file exists and does contain a [cache] section:

```
[cache]
type=Disk
#base=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\tilecache\Cache
base=g:\tilecache\Cache
```

Using SysInternals ProcessMonitor I've determined that python.exe never attempts to access tilecache.cfg.

Renaming tilecache.cfg results in the same error.  Why isn't it loading the file?  Is the path incorrectly formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution is to put [brackets] around the path to the tilecache.cfg file:

So modify tilecache.py to look like this:

```
from TileCache import Service, cgiHandler, cfgfiles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    svc = Service.load(["d:\\code\\tilecache\\tilecache.cfg"])
    cgiHandler(svc)
```